# How a criminal speeding citation of 104 mph in a 75 mph zone will affect my immigration status (F1 visa)?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, traffic, immigration, arizona

I recently received a criminal speeding citation for driving at 104 mph in 75 mph zone in Arizona. I have clean driving history without any prior citation or accident. I am an international citizen on an F1 visa. How will this citation affect my current and future immigration status?

Comment: I don't believe this is off topic. While the circumstances are individual, it asks a specific question about the law which can be answered. It does not ask for legal advice (i.e. "what should I do?").

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Expartes.SE